# Why is MeshRegion atomic?

Tags: regions, mesh, language-design

I wanted to make some changes inside a `MeshRegion` today and found that unlike `Graphics` objects, it can't be done directly because it is atomic (`AtomQ` returns true).

The functionalities I came across so far won't be effected if it is not atomic, even the `MeshRegion[something]["Properties"]` can be achieved like `FittedModel`, which is not atomic. Being atomic, operations like changing something inside, retrieve information other than coordinates(`MeshCoordinates`) become difficult.

I would like to know what is the advantage/motivation to make it atomic.